# How do i check for all matches in two lists in python?

Tags: python

I am creating a word in a word type game and I have to compare the users input to the list of words you can make out of the set letters, and count the matches. I have been trying to find an answer to this problem but haven't, i am not very good at coding at all, maybe its really simple but i'm having issues, please help.

The code is for my project at school and it is to design some software that works and I wanted to create a word in a word type of game but I am having trouble using the help of the internet just off of searches so i'm hoping someone can answer this.

```
import re
MW = "waterfall"
Words = "1. waterfall 2. flatware 3. lateral 4. lawfare 5. faller 6. 
falter 7. rafale 8. refall 9. relata 10. taller 11. tellar 12. wafter 
13. waller 14. wallet 15. afear 16. after 17. alate 18. aleft 19. 
alert 
20. altar 21. alter 22. areal 23. artal 24. artel 25. aware 26. farle 
27. fatal 28. fatwa 29. feart 30. fella 31. feral 32. fetal 33. fetwa 
34. flare 35. frate 36. later 37. lawer 38. ratal 39. ratel 40. reata 
41. talar 42. talea 43. taler 44. tawer 45. trawl 46. trefa 47. wafer 
48. waler 49. walla 50. water 51. wrate 52. afar 53. alae 54. alar 55. 
alef 56. alew 57. alfa 58. area 59. aret 60. arew 61. arle 62. earl 
63. 
fall 64. fare 65. farl 66. fart 67. fate 68. feal 69. fear 70. feat 
71. 
fell 72. felt 73. feta 74. flat 75. flaw 76. flea 77. flew 78. frae 
79. 
frat 80. fret 81. laer 82. lare 83. late 84. leaf 85. leal 86. lear 
87. 
leat 88. left 89. raft 90. rale 91. rata 92. rate 93. real 94. reft 
95. 
taal 96. tael 97. tala 98. tale 99. tall 100. tara 101. tare 102. tawa 
103. teal 104. tear 105. tela 106. tell 107. terf 108. tref 109. trew 
110. twae 111. twal 112. waft 113. wale 114. wall 115. ware 116. wart 
117. wate 118. weal 119. wear 120. weft 121. well 122. welt 123. wert 
124. weta 125. aal 126. aft 127. ala 128. ale 129. alf 130. all 131. 
alt 132. are 133. arf 134. art 135. ate 136. awa 137. awe 138. awl 
139. 
ear 140. eat 141. eft 142. elf 143. ell 144. elt 145. era 146. erf 
147. 
eta 
148. ewt 149. faa 150. fae 151. far 152. fat 153. faw 154. fer 155. 
fet 
156. few 157. fra 158. lar 159. lat 160. law 161. lea 162. let 163. 
lew 
164. rat 165. raw 166. ref 167. ret 168. rew 169. tae 170. tar 171. 
taw 
172. tea 173. tef 174. tel 175. tew 176. twa 177. wae 178. war 179. 
wat 
180. wet 181. aa 182. ae 183. al 184. ar 185. at 186. aw 187. ea 188. 
ef 189. el 190. er 191. et 192. fa 193. fe 194. la 195. re 196. ta 
197. 
te 198. we"
y = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', Words)
W = ''.join([i for i in y if not i.isdigit()])
Draw = W.split()

print(MW)
input_string = input("Type all the words you can find in the above 
words/word, separated by a comma:\n")
A = input_string.replace(" "," ").split(",")

for A in A:
    matchCount = 0
    if A in Draw:
        matchCount += 1
print (matchCount)

def common_data(Draw, A):
    common = 0
    for x in Draw:
        for y in A:
            if x == y:
                common += 1
                print (x)
```

the output of this code when I enter two words is 0, but I want it to be however many words i have typed that are correct.

Comment: What did the user input and what is the list of words that you are comparing it too. In this case is the word waterfall? Then there is only one match?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is a nested for loop if you just want to compare two lists

Comment: The first thing I would do is store your words in a suitable data structure. I wouldn't clean it up each time you run it, but rather before you run. That will make your code more readable. Then use python sets to find the intersection of the user lists and yours.

Comment: Agent Lu yeah just for now as a start the word that you use to make other words is waterfall and that big string that gets converted to a list is all the words you can create, when I test it I input (waterfall, flatware) the first two words, but it doesn't work

Comment: sakurashinken i will try to do that, although i'm not very experienced, most of this code i have been helped from the internet, sorry

Comment: @Ivalidname1289 Hey if my answer worked for you can you checkmark it. Thanks!

Comment: @Ivalidname1289 can you checkmark my answer if it worked?

Answer (score 0):

One way to compare two lists is by using a nested for loop, or a for loop inside of a for loop. One loop would be for user input and the other for your list.

```py
userlist = ["apple", "banana", etc]
yourlist = ["apple", "cat", "banana"]
counter = 0
for userword in userlist:
    for yourword in yourlist:
         if userword == yourword:
              counter = counter + 1
print(counter)
```

counter is the amount of matches between the two lists.

Comment: Let me know if this is not the answer you wanted

Comment: Thank you a lot i'm still learning and this helped, it was a part of a big problem you help solve

Comment: @Ivalidname1289 can you checkmark my question if it helped you?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are setting `matchCount` inside the loop, so it resets to zero before it checks each word. Just move it outside the loop, and you should get the results you want.

Don't feel bad about this mistake—it's the kind of simple thing everyone gets wrong at some point.

---

Besides my answer, I offer this advice regarding your code:

You shouldn't use the name of your loop target as the loop variable. Using `for A in A:` will overwrite the value of `A` even after the loop finishes.

In Python, you can create multi-line strings by using triple-quotes (`"""` or `'''`). This makes using long data strings much nicer, though sakurashinken's suggestion that you pre-format the data is probably a better idea than keeping it as one long string.

Don't capitalize the first letter of variable names—that treatment is usually reserved for [classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html), and is why Stack Overflow highlights those words in a different shade than other names. (All-caps is usually reserved for constants.)

You can use the regular expression that creates `y` to create `W` without the extra step of a list comprehension: `re.sub(r'[\W\d]', ' ', words)` will replace both non-word characters and digits. Then you can create `Draw` from `Words` in one line.

Comment: I thank you very much I didn't expect such a quit response